# How to add a filtered value across other filtered values

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have data like this

| Person | Total Count |
| --- | --- |
| First | 5 |
| Second | 6 |
| Third | 5 |
| Null | 6 |

I want to take the nulls, divide by 3 (number of people), and add that number to each of the [Person]'s [Total Count] column. So, I want it to look like this:

| Person | Total Count |
| --- | --- |
| First | 7 |
| Second | 8 |
| Third | 7 |
| Null | 6 |

Comment: In your raw data, do you have 5 records with the value "First" in the "Person" column? Or do you have 1 record with the value "First" in the "Person" column and the value 5 in a column named "Total Count"?

Comment: good question - It's the first option. "First" appears 5 times in the raw data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following on some shelf with Person on Rows

MIN( { SUM(INT(ISNULL([Person]))) / COUNTD([Person]) } ) + Count([Person])

Comment: I've run into this problem before but doing this gives me the error (while typing this as a calculated field) that I "can't mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function"

Comment: Try the revised answer

Comment: hmm I think we're getting somewhere. Now, I am getting results in the "Total Count" column (before I was getting 0's there with only the null row populating the number of nulls). However, the numbers are off in the Total Count column. I

Comment: if you revise the post to show the actual raw data and the values you are getting for Total Count, then it might be possible to give feedback. However "the numbers are off" is a bit too vague to respond to usefully.